# Difference in supports of $\delta$ and $\delta$' distributions

Tags: distribution-theory

From my understanding of distributions, the distribution, $T$, is defined as $0$ on the set $\Omega$ when $T(\phi)=0$ for all test functions $\phi$ with support $\Omega$. Further the support of the distribution is the complement of the set of points and its neighborhoods where $T$ is zero.

From this definition, I can understand how the $\delta$ and $\delta'$ distributions have the support $0$. However, I recently read from an excerpt of a textbook that the $\delta'$ distribution "hangs on at least infinitesimally, beyond its support." From what I know, both distributions are supported in a neighborhood of $0$, but what I'm struggling to understand is how $\delta'$ could be supported beyond that neighborhood.
I included the excerpt below with the sentence that is confusing me highlighted.

[image]

Comment: This is meant as some kind of intuition, and it is true that $\delta'$ is *only* supported at $0$.  One example for why it is useful to think of $\delta'$ as having "slightly wider" support is that $x\delta' \not= 0$, so $\delta'$ does not get annihilated by multiplying it against a function that vanishes on its support.  This is counterintuitive, so it might be helpful to think of $\delta'$ as having "slightly wider" support, even though it is not true.

Comment: @Timothy It is just a poor choice of words to say that $\delta'$ computes one derivative of any test function at $0$, and such derivative requires the function to be defined on an open neighbourhood of $0$. "Hangs on infinitesimally beyond the support" means that in order to compute $\phi'$ we need the values of $\phi$ outside of the singleton $\{0\}$ but arbitrarily close to it (hence "infinitesimally"). The rigorous meaning is clarified in the sentence right after the one you highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

By the definition of the derivatives of a distribution,$$\langle \delta',\phi \rangle = -\langle \delta,\phi' \rangle$$ $\delta'$ "depends on the (infinitesimal) neighborhood of 0" since the definition of $\delta'$ is dependent on the derivative of $\phi$.